# Error in iconv(x, if (any(idx)) "UTF-8" else "", to) : null embedded in chain

Tags: r, knitr

I'm on a brand new installation of R 3.4.0 and Rstudio 1.0.143 on an x64 Windows 10 PC.  All the packages I'm using are up to date.  When I try to create an Rmarkdown file from scratch and knit it, I get the following error message after the chunks are done processing:

```
Error in iconv(x, if (any(idx)) "UTF-8" else "", to) : 
null embedded in chain: '\0\0þÿ\0\0\0-\0\0\0-\0\0\0-
\0\0\0\n\0\0\0t\0\0\0i\0\0\0t\0\0\0l\0\0\0e\0\0\0:\0\0\0 ... (output truncated)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> writeLines -> native_encode -> iconv
Execution interrupted
```

Apparently, this only happens when the file is encoded as UTF-32, as I set it as the default for my project.  When I change the encoding for this very file to UTF-8 it gets solved.

Not sure why this happens, but I haven't been able to find any info about this error on the web.  Any help will be much appreciated.

P.S.: Some of the error messages may not be correct (I translated them manually from Spanish), but that's what they say basically.

Comment: If you want to make everybody's life easier, always use UTF-8 when choosing the character encoding. My biggest regret in developing knitr is that I didn't enforce UTF-8 in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I decided to use UTF-32 because I thought there could be some trouble with non-standard characters (e.g., ñ, á, é, í, etc.) which are rather common in my docs when I write in Spanish.  but apparently UTF-8 can manage with those.